# Need to query remote API with MySQL stored procedure/http post method

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, http-post

I want to use a stored procedure in MySQL to send 2 variables to a remote API with HTTP Post, then get the response and write it to a new table. The procedure so far is below, as far as I can gather wget would work.

The IP address and timestamp will of course change. If this is going over http post I also need the field names as part of the URL sent.

How can I add the variables to the URL in a single block?

```
DELIMITER$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mpTest2$$
CREATE PROCEDURE mpTest2(INOUT ipqAddress VARCHAR(16), INOUT ipqTime DATETIME)

BEGIN
 DECLARE URI VARCHAR(30) = '';
 DECLARE apiKey VARCHAR(--) = ...
 DECLARE method VARCHAR(15);
 -- declare ipAddress varchar(16);
 -- declare ipTime    datetime;
 DECLARE lCount INT; -- counter for cursor
 DECLARE lflag INT;

 DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR
    SELECT mpalltrans.`IP`
    FROM mpalltrans;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET lflag=1;

OPEN curl;
ipqloop:LOOP
    FETCH curl INTO ipaddress
    IF lflag = 1 THEN
        LEAVE ipqloop;
    wget http://www.w.cookies/ ***Need to insert table variables here with predefined field names***
END LOOP iploop;
CLOSE curl;
END;
DELIMITER$$
```

Thank you,
J

Comment: In reality, this is probably better in a script (PHP, Perl, etc.), instead of making a SQL database do non-SQL things (wgets,etc.)

Comment: What I am finding so far is leaning towards PHP, the only problem is I don't know PHP yet.